# Problem to run "anaconda-navigator"

Tags: command-line, python, anaconda

I was not able to run the command `anaconda-navigator`, so I followed the following procedure:

```
$ source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root
$ anaconda-navigator
```

After this, Anaconda Navigator opened, but when I restart the computer, I have to do this again. Is there a way to run it just with the `anaconda-navigator` command?

Answer (score 0):

You may add the `source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root` command at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file so the command will be executed for any new terminal you open.

You can either add it using a text editor (e.g. `nano`) or by running the following command:

```
echo "source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then open a new terminal and the `root` Python environment will be activated, so you will be able to use `anaconda-navigator` immediately.